# Как нажать на канал с помощью Selenium

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, selenium

Всем добрый день. Пишу парсер на Python, который парсит название и ссылки с каналов на  https://yandex.ru/chat/#/

Есть код, но проблема в том, что когда нажимаю  помощью селениума на первый канал, то открывается первый канал. Добываю ссылку с помощью     linkk2 = driver.current_url

Но классы у всех каналов одинаковые, он всё время нажимает на первый канал. Прикрепил код и скриншот.

Comment: Используйте find_element**s**_by_css_selector, чтобы получить все элементы, а не только один (первый)

Comment: Но дело в том, что нужно на каждый нажать и тогда получить ссылку от каждого канала с помощью driver.current_url

Comment: channel = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".yamb-entity-block.yamb-chat-list-item-block")
        channel.click()
        linkk = driver.current_url

Comment: Возникает ошибка при click(). Получить ссылку получается только так, ведь там href нет в html теге

Comment: Не, там ведь список будет, поэтому кликать нужно именно на каждый канал по отдельности, т.е. `for channel in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".yamb-entity-block.yamb-chat-list-item-block"): channel.click()`

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Как засчитать этот ответ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно получить список элементов, представляющих каналами, используя метод `find_elements_by_css_selector`, и кликнуть по каждому:

```
for channel in driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(".yamb-entity-block.yamb-chat-list-item-block"):
    channel.click()
    linkk2 = driver.current_url
    print(linkk2)
```