# Как спарсить html тег?

Tags: python

Всем добрый день. Есть скрипт, который парсит эту страницу: https://lenta.com/

Вот что программа выводит:

```
<div class="js-current-store header__location-picker" data-city-key="spb" data-customer-id="dbee0084-e086-4da0-959a-5d2059976298" data-ga-event-category="catalog:header" data-is-default-city="True" data-is-default-store="True" data-is-store-picked="False" data-should-render-store-picker="False" data-store='{"id":"0006","address":"д. Старо-Паново, ш. Таллинское, д. 159, лит. А","cityKey":"spb","cityName":"Санкт-Петербург","type":"hypermarket","lat":59.807053,"long":30.162049,"opensAt":"0","closesAt":"0","is24hStore":true,"hasPetShop":true}'>
<div class="current-store">
<div class="tooltips-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
```

Как сделать вывод в таком виде:

```
data-store='{"id":"0006","address":"д. Старо-Паново, ш. Таллинское, д. 159, лит. А","cityKey":"spb","cityName":"Санкт-Петербург","type":"hypermarket","lat":59.807053,"long":30.162049,"opensAt":"0","closesAt":"0","is24hStore":true,"hasPetShop":true}'>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вытащите у того элемента атрибут `data-store` и разберите как `json`:

```
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """
<div class="js-current-store header__location-picker" data-city-key="spb" data-customer-id="dbee0084-e086-4da0-959a-5d2059976298" data-ga-event-category="catalog:header" data-is-default-city="True" data-is-default-store="True" data-is-store-picked="False" data-should-render-store-picker="False" data-store='{"id":"0006","address":"д. Старо-Паново, ш. Таллинское, д. 159, лит. А","cityKey":"spb","cityName":"Санкт-Петербург","type":"hypermarket","lat":59.807053,"long":30.162049,"opensAt":"0","closesAt":"0","is24hStore":true,"hasPetShop":true}'>
<div class="current-store">
<div class="tooltips-container"></div>
</div>
</div>
"""
root = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')

el = root.select_one('.js-current-store')
data_store = json.loads(el['data-store'], encoding='utf-8')
print(data_store)
# {'id': '0006', 'address': 'д. Старо-Паново, ш. Таллинское, д. 159, лит. А', 'cityKey': 'spb', 'cityName': 'Санкт-Петербург', 'type': 'hypermarket', 'lat': 59.807053, 'long': 30.162049, 'opensAt': '0', 'closesAt': '0', 'is24hStore': True, 'hasPetShop': True}

print(data_store['id'])
# 0006
```

Comment: Работает, спасибо! Как будет время, подскажите пожалуйста с этим вопросом: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1135615/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%b6%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-selenium

Comment: @Евгений, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ и отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)

Comment: Цитирую: "Вы можете принять ответ через 3 минуты"

Comment: @Евгений, извините, что сомневался в вас :D

Comment: Спасибо за ответ на этот вопрос!